# Selecting data from a range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, excel-formula

first of all thanks for your time. I have an excel file with a matrix similar to this:

[image: Matrix]

And I have a function in VBA that, for a given date c, it select the previous date and the posterior date. That is the function:

```
Function Dates(ByVal date, matrix) As Double
If TypeName(matrix) = "Range" Then matrix = matrix
nCols = UBound(matrix, 2)

If date > matrix(1, nCols) Then date = matrix(1, nCols)
If date < matrix(1, 1) Then date = matrix(1, 1)

date1 = 1
While date > matrix(1, date1) And date1 <= nCols
    date1 = date1 + 1
Wend
 date1 = date1 - 1

If date1 = 1 Then date1 = 2
If date1 >= nCols Then date1 = nCols - 1
date2 = date1 + 1
End Function
```

I think that is correct. The value date is the date which it will be used to obtain the previous date and the posterior date of that date. and matrix is the matrix of the picture, but what I need is that when the previous and the posterior dates are selected (date1 and date2), the values of each date, I need them to do some operation. Something like this:
For a date date = 26/9/2016, the previous date (date1) is 29/07/2016 and the posterior  date (date2) is 29/10/2016. What I want to obtain is:

```
29/07/2016       29/07/2016
 15,58%            15,58%
 8,21%              8,21%
 5,65%              5,65%
   .                  .
   .                  .
   .                  .
 1,39%              1,46%
```

And then, be able to do a loop through those column to perform an interpolation to obtain the values for the date.
Is possible to do that? If you can help me I would appreciate it
Thank you so much for taking your time to read and trying to help.

Comment: Please show how you call the function. Also declare types for the variables `ByVal c, v` • This `v = v` doesn't make any sense at all. • Have a look at the [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) • Name your variables meaningfull `c`, `v` and `c1` are the worst names you can choose. • Fix that and activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. Then [edit] your question and update the code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ wasn't this question already asked yesterday and answered by you?

Comment: @VincentG Yes, yesterday the question was just about the interpolation and very very broad without any code etc, where I just gave a hint about the mathematics behind that. But this seems to be a bit more detailed now (the issue seems to be to find the data here).

Comment: @Amartin And your code is incomplete, the function doesn't return anything and there is no `End Function`. You might also have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) to find your date easily.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I edit the question. Sorry if I make mistakes but I am new in VBA and I don't understand most of the things. The problem if that when I select date1 and date2, is possible to loop throug them to use it to make an interpolation?

Comment: `date` is a variable type you cannot use it as variable name, it is a reserved keyword. Also you did not try any of the functions I linked. You must put in a bit more effort here, we can assist you but we cannot do all the work for you. Start reading about the `.Match` method and try to use this to locate the column of your dates in the first row. Then use `.Offset` to find the previous and next date, and also to find the data (`.Resize` might help for the data too). Give that a try.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I will try. Thank you and sorry for my poor knowledge on VBA.

Comment: @Amartin No need to be sorry about your knowlegde, everyone of us started somewhere. Just give our suggestions a try, you will learn it by trying, failing, researching, reading, trying again, failing again, etc. Takes its time but you will learn it.